# Why image in react native is not updated when changed on disk?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I download image in the phone documents folder path like:

```
/app/documents/coverPhoto.jpg
```

And I reference it in app like:

```
<Image source={{uri: "/app/documents/coverPhoto.jpg"}} />
```

The I download a new photo from url and overwrite image in documents folder.
And image in app is not refreshed so I need to restart app in order to see new image.
Is it possible to update image on disk and to refresh `<Image/>` as soon as image is changed?

Comment: use refresh functionality in your app to reload image whenever you comeback to the page with image, you cannot expect your app to look for "imagechange" everytime your overwrite the image.

Comment: "use refresh functionality " can you give some example what is refresh functionality?

Comment: Hi @1110 did you solve it?